# what does git bundle command do?

Tags: git

I have been asked to do a project (react-firebase).

On submission one of the instruction is to run

```
git bundle create ../${PWD##*/}.bundle --all to create a .bundle file with the repo contents
```

I am not sure what the above means. Can someone help in figuring what I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

`git bundle create ../${PWD##*/}.bundle --all` creates a bundle whose path is `../${PWD##*/}.bundle`. The bundle is like a mirror image of the repository with all refs (by `--all`). It works as a read-only repository.

For example, you can run `git clone <path_to_bundle>` to create a cloned repository, `git fetch <path_to_bundle> master` to fetch `master` from the bundle, `git ls-remote` to list all the refs in the bundle. But it would fail if you run `git push <path_to_bundle> master`. It's read-only for git commands.

Comment: I advice to explain that `${PWD##*/}` means: get the value of env var `$PWD` which is the full path to the current directory and cut from it all components separated by `/`. The result is the base name of the current dir. A more readable (at least for me) equivalent is `$(basename $PWD)` but it's slower as it requires to run a program while `${PWD##*/}` brace expansion is implemented in bash directly.